# Openlayers display Large data , browser issue

Tags: internet-explorer-7, openlayers, freeze, large-data

i have a map with large data set(more than 100k), with markers, and ma using Geojson format with cluster, and BBox strategy, [fetching geojson data through HTTP request on starting the page]

but my browser(IE7,8) has problem with large amount of data, its going stuck while processing the large amount of features and shows error message - Out of memory

is there any solution ?

please help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Drawing 100k features on the client is not so good idea. Even "good" browsers will slow down attempting to render that much data. You have a couple of options though:

1. Generate images with data on the server side and serve tiles to the client. A WMS service is a way to go in this case and you can use [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/), [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/) or other WMS-compliant map rendering engine. You can then use GetFeatureInfo requests to fetch attribute data for features. You can see an example of how it works in this [OpenLayers demo](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html)
2. If you data is static and doesn't change much you can create tiles using [Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/) and then use them in OpenLayers as OpenLayers.Layer.TMS layer. You can then use [UTFGrid](http://mapbox.com/mbtiles-spec/utfgrid/) tecnique to map attribute data to tiles. [Here's an example](http://mapbox.com/demo/visiblemap/) of how it  works.

Comment: Sorry for late feedback
can you please tell me how the first option will work using geoserver